# Get module handle to Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, popen

I'm trying to take the assigned object from an open Popen object, then assign it to something global in the module so that I can query it from my main function. sort of like this:

```
class TestController (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.test_status=object
        print "You have initialized the TestController"
    def start_test(self, input):
        test_handle = Popen([args])
        self.test_status=test_handle
    def check_testStatus(self):
        print self.test_status.poll()


def main():
   print "Main function is now running"
   testHandle = TestController()
   testHandle.start_test("this")
   testHandle.check_testStatus()


def showmenu():
    prompt = """
(N)ew User Login
(E)xisting User Login
(Q)uit

Enter choice: """
    main()

    done = 0
    while not done:
        chosen = 0
        while not chosen:
            try:
                choice = raw_input(prompt)[0]
            except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
                choice = 'q'
            print '\nYou picked: [%s]' % choice

            if choice not in 'neqs':
                print 'invalid menu option, try again'
            else:
                chosen = 1

        if choice == 'q': done = 1
        if choice == 'n': newuser()
        if choice == 'e': olduser()
        if choice == 's': report_test_status()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    showmenu()
```

It doesn't work though. can someone please tell me what im doing wrong.

Comment: I'm having to guess at what you're actually asking, since I can't see anywhere in your code that's trying to query the Popen object outside of the class it's encapsulated in. Maybe it's the `report_test_status` function you expect to query it? In which case, we'd need to see that code to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable test_handle is in the module namespace, it needs to specified as a global:

```
test_handle = None

class TestController (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.test_status=object
        print "You have initialized the TestController"
    def start_test(self, input):
        global test_handle
        test_handle = Popen([args])
        self.test_status=test_handle
    def check_testStatus(self):
        print self.test_status.poll()
```

Comment: Where do i put this and how do i initialize it? test_handle=object?

Comment: I keep getting AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'poll'

Comment: @seasick Maybe you're calling `check_testStatus` before you call start_test`? Where is your error occuring?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, because you didn't give us much to go on.  I've chosen to use a class variable instead of a global, but you could also do this with a global.

```
class TestController (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.test_status=object
        print "You have initialized the TestController"
    def start_test(self, input):
        test_handle = Popen([args])
        TestController.test_status=test_handle
    def check_testStatus(self):
        print self.test_status.poll()

def main():
   print(TestController.test_status)
```

Answer (score 0):

With some stub functions, the following is working for me.  Sorry, I'm using a newer version of Python.

```
from subprocess import Popen
test_handle = None    
class TestController (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.test_status=object
        print("You have initialized the TestController")
    def start_test(self, app):
        global test_handle
        test_handle = Popen(app)
        self.test_status=test_handle
    def check_testStatus(self):
        print(self.test_status.poll())

def report_test_status():
    "Report test status"

def main():
   print("Main function is now running")
   testHandle = TestController()
   testHandle.start_test("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe")
   testHandle.check_testStatus()


def showmenu():
    prompt = """
(N)ew User Login
(E)xisting User Login
(Q)uit

Enter choice: """
    main()

    done = 0
    while not done:
        chosen = 0
        while not chosen:
            try:
                choice = input(prompt)[0]
            except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
                choice = 'q'
            print('\nYou picked: [%s]' % choice)

            if choice not in 'neqs':
                print('invalid menu option, try again')
            else:
                chosen = 1

        if choice == 'q': done = 1
        if choice == 'n': newuser()
        if choice == 'e': olduser()
        if choice == 's': report_test_status()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    showmenu()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `newuser()`, `olduser()` and `report_test_status()` want to reference `testHandle` that's defined in `main()`. I can't be sure, because you haven't shown us what those functions do, and it not obvious what part of your code you're expecting to act differently.

So, what I *think* you're trying to do, is this:

near the top, have:

```
testHandle = None
```

Not actually necessary, but allows people reading the code to see that there's a global variable easily.

Then, declare testHandle as global in your `main()` function with the `global` keyword:

```
def main():
    global testHandle
    print "Main function is now running"
    testHandle = TestController()
    testHandle.start_test("this")
    testHandle.check_testStatus()
```

That way, when you assign to `testHandle` inside main, you'll assign to the global (read: module level) variable, instead of creating a new local variable that's only visible inside the function.

I would say that this isn't a great way to design your code though. I think a much better solution would be to have your `main()` function return the `testHandle` object, and then make `newuser()` and the others methods of the `TestController` class instead.

Comment: Do you mean return the object from TestController and query it from Main?

Comment: It depends on what you're actually trying to do. Again, please edit your question to make this clear. I'd suggest adding methods onto TestController to do the queries you want rather than returning the Popen object, but you could access the Popen object itself if you wanted. In main, this would be as `testHandle.test_status`